# bulbs rexster system error

Tags: bulbs, rexster

I am using Rexster 2.4.0 and Bulbs 0.3.14

With Rexster running on localhost, I am trying to get familiar with Bulbs, yet when trying:

```
>>>from bulbs.rexster import Graph
>>>g = Graph()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
File "/Users/lolmac/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/rexster/graph.py", line 54, in **init**
    super(Graph, self).**init**(config)

File "/Users/lolmac/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/base/graph.py", line 58, in **init**
    self.vertices = self.build_proxy(Vertex)

File "/Users/lolmac/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/base/graph.py", line 124, in build_proxy
    return self.factory.build_element_proxy(element_class, index_class)

File "/Users/lolmac/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/factory.py", line 19, in build_element_proxy
    primary_index = self.get_index(element_class,index_class,index_name)

File "/Users/lolmac/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/factory.py", line 27, in get_index
    index = index_proxy.get_or_create(index_name)

File "/Users/lolmac/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/rexster/index.py", line 80, in get_or_create
    resp = self.client.get_or_create_vertex_index(index_name, index_params)

File "/Users/lolmac/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/rexster/client.py", line 660, in get_or_create_vertex_index
    resp = self.gremlin(script, params)

File "/Users/lolmac/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/rexster/client.py", line 354, in gremlin
    return self.request.post(gremlin_path,params)

File "/Users/lolmac/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/rest.py", line 128, in post
    return self.request(POST, path, params)

File "/Users/lolmac/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/rest.py", line 183, in request
    return self.response_class(http_resp, self.config)

File "/Users/lolmac/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/rexster/client.py", line 198, in **init**
    self.handle_response(response)

File "/Users/lolmac/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/rexster/client.py", line 222, in handle_response
    response_handler(http_resp)

File "/Users/lolmac/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/rest.py", line 50, in server_error
    raise SystemError(http_resp)

SystemError: ({'status': '500', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'server': 'grizzly/2.2.16', 'connection': 'close', 'date': 'Mon, 14 Oct 2013 19:43:45 GMT', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'content-type': 'application/json'}, '{"message":"","error":"javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException.stopTransaction() is applicable for argument types: () values: []","api":{"description":"evaluate an ad-hoc Gremlin script for a graph.","parameters":{"rexster.returnKeys":"an array of element property keys to return (default is to return all element properties)","rexster.showTypes":"displays the properties of the elements with their native data type (default is false)","load":"a list of \'stored procedures\' to execute prior to the \'script\' (if \'script\' is not specified then the last script in this argument will return the values","rexster.offset.end":"end index for a paged set of data to be returned","rexster.offset.start":"start index for a paged set of data to be returned","params":"a map of parameters to bind to the script engine","language":"the gremlin language flavor to use (default to groovy)","script":"the Gremlin script to be evaluated"}},"success":false}')

this is an old post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gremlin-users/s7Ag1tjbxLs/kaBOSyed_9kJ, but it seems other folks encountered the same problem. Still, i was not able to find any documentation that indicates what is wrong or what to change in the default configuration.

grateful to any docs/discussions or ideas that can provide a hint.

Comment: Can you provide the details of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because Bulbs 0.3.14 hadn't been updated to TinkerPop 2.4, but that's fixed now -- I just updated Bulbs-Rexster to TinkerPop 2.5.0-SNAPSHOT and pushed the Bulbs 0.3.15 to both GitHub and PyPi. All tests pass. Please let me know if that fixes it for you.

Comment: Yes, I can verify it fixes the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: How do you update? or how do you make sure that the versions match?